# Exception handling in Scanner

Tags: java

Is it necessary to handle exceptions when using the Scanner class in java. How can you explain about this?

I do not have correct idea about this. Any one can help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post snippet of code where you are running into problem.

Comment: @Sameera, what are you trying to do? Please share some examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any use of methods that throws exceptions should handle, rethrow, or redeclare (if it is a *checked* exception) them for the next level up to choose what to do with it.

In `Scanner`, if you take [`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) method, it throws various exceptions depending on the status of the scanner. You have to care about it.
But the way to care depend on your program logic.

That said, most exceptions in `Scanner` are `RuntimeException`, meaning you don't need to *explicitly* catch them in your code. Assuming you are in a `main`, if an exception occurs, it will be handled by at top level by the JVM. I this case, your program will exit with an error code and a stacktrace.

The only exceptions in `Scanner` which are *checked* and that you must handle in some way, is when you construct a `Scanner` from a files. `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException` cannot be ignored.

---

As an example of (abused) usage of exceptions when you read a `double`, you may be tempted to do:

```
public static void testScanDoubleWithException() {
    Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a double: ");
    while (true) {
        try {
            double d = sin.nextDouble(); // Throw if not a double
            System.out.println("Read double value: "+d);
            break;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid double, shoot again:");
            sin.nextLine(); // consume bad input
        }
    }
    sin.close();
}
```

But the `Scanner` class provides the more simple/explicit way:

```
public static void testScanDouble() {
    Scanner sin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a double: ");
    while (!sin.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid double, shoot again:");
        sin.nextLine();
    }
    double d = sin.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Read double value: "+d);
    sin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java supports exceptions handling so that we can avoid unwanted behaviors in our applications. During any transaction, if we foresee any unwanted behaviors we should handle exceptions. Scanner class can throw any exception based on the type of operation used, eg Runtime, illegalArgument, numberformat etc. thus as a good practice we should always catch all specific exceptions individually and have a better execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example, if you are using a Scanner object to read a file, you should handle the FileNotFoundException otherwise there will be an error. However, if you are simply using System.in as input, no error will be displayed. But, at the same time, you should check if the input is according to what you wanted from the user, hence it is always advisable to make use of exception handling.